# How would one go about creating a workflow for activities?

Tags: activities, permissions, workflow

I'm thinking something like the following:

1. Employee enters an activity entitled Check Request and submits it.
2. It is automatically submitted to his/her supervisor(based on preconfigured rule).
3. Supervisor either approves request whereby it automatically goes to appropriate person to cut the check. If denied then it is assigned back to the employee.

I can deal with it not doing the assigning automatically but it does need some way to show that each level signed off on/approved the request. Just having each person put a comment in the Description section of the activity is not enough because it could easily be "cheated" by the employee just putting in comments. What's the best suggestion on having some sort of "approval history" for an activity?

Just a note: CiviCase is wayyy overkill for this.

Comment: My first thought is to use statusses for this. Request approval, approval denied etc... And that each supervisor has a report with the activities with a certain status. If you want to fully automate this process you could have a look at CiviRules.

Comment: Yes but that doesn't show a history of who approved it each time. Basically that activity needs to have a visible change log on it.

Comment: why don't you try creating an new activity when the status gets changed - by this way you can easily differentiate the activity by the user who has changed the status - sorry if I am wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have server permissions to implement this, I think a binary log is the best approach.  Turn on binary logging at **Administer menu > System Settings > Misc** by setting "Logging" to "Yes".

At this point, you'll have a complete history of who made what changes in a SQL table called`log_civicrm_activity`.  To add a "visible change log" to the activity is a little trickier - you can probably write a custom report pretty easily, but to add the data directly to the activity page, you'd need to create a small extension that injected the data onto the activity.

Comment: I'll look at this. Sounds like it might be best option. I'm see if it presents the info i want and go from there.

Comment: wondering if just writing a php script and appending it to the activity template and having it determine if the activity type is XX would be just as good? utilizing the method described here http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Page+Templates  under the Appending jquery and other code